# OpenJPA - Extending PersistenceMappingDefaults to convert Camel-Case to Underscores

Tags: jpa, openjpa

```
public class ImprovedMappingDefaults extends PersistenceMappingDefaults {
    @Override
    protected void correctName(Table table, Column col) {
        String name = col.getName();
        name = addUnderscores(name);
        col.setName(dict.getValidColumnName(name, table));
    }

    // taken from Hibernate's ImprovedNamingStrategy
    private static String addUnderscores(String name) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(name.replace('.', '_'));
        for (int i = 1; i < buf.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i - 1)) && Character.isUpperCase(buf.charAt(i)) && Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i + 1))) {
                buf.insert(i++, '_');
            }
        }
        return buf.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

The above code generates DDL correctly in Openjpa 1.2.2 by converting camel case field names to underscores in the db. However persistence operations like em.persist() generate erroneous SQL and fails.

```
org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: Column not found: VERSION5 in statement [INSERT INTO FOO_FILE (file_id, VERSION5, DATETIME05, FILE_NAME5, INPUT_SYSTEM5, IS_END_OF_DAY5, SEQUENCE_NUMBER5, TOTAL_AMOUNT5, TOTAL_COUNT5, MY_FILE_ID5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)] {INSERT INTO FOO_FILE (file_id, VERSION5, DATETIME05, FILE_NAME5, INPUT_SYSTEM5, IS_END_OF_DAY5, SEQUENCE_NUMBER5, TOTAL_AMOUNT5, TOTAL_COUNT5, MY_FILE_ID5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} [code=-28, state=S0022]
```

Note that openjpa is appending "5" to each column. Not sure where this is coming from. The DDL for FOO_FILE generated is:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO_FILE (file_id BIGINT NOT NULL, VERSION INTEGER, DATETIME0 TIME, FILE_NAME VARCHAR(100), INPUT_SYSTEM VARCHAR(3), IS_END_OF_DAY BIT, SEQUENCE_NUMBER BIGINT, TOTAL_AMOUNT NUMERIC, TOTAL_COUNT INTEGER, MY_FILE_ID VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (file_id))
```

Just to double check if my logic was wrong, I replaced correctName() with the super class method (that uses Hungarian notation).

```
protected void correctName(Table table, Column col) {
    String name = col.getName();
    name = removeHungarianNotation(name);
    col.setName(dict.getValidColumnName(name, table));
}
```

That fails too.

Has anyone successfully extended PersistenceMappingDefaults to change column/table names? It seems openjpa is too complicated compared to Hibernate in this regard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works in current versions of OpenJPA. See [example here](http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/Change-of-MappingDefaults-breaks-OPENJPA-SEQUENCE-TABLE-td7580246.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code above and it works for OpenJPA 2.2.0.

Successfully mapped camel-case field names to underscores in db.

So field `private String taxRate;` refers to db column `TAX_RATE` without having to annotate with `@Column(name = 'TAX_RATE')`

Remember that the persistence.xml needs a property like this to be defined in the `<persistence-unit>`:

```
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults"
            value="com.myproject.ImprovedMappingDefaults"/>
    </properties>
```

It would be great if the OpenJPA team could take this in as an option, like *removeHungarianNotation*...